# Split multiple items in a string

Tags: powershell

Get-EC2Instance |%{ $*.RunningInstance } | select-object InstanceId,@{Name='Key'; Expression={$*.Tag.Key} },@{Name='Value'; Expression={$_.Tag.Value} }

This command displays below output. Each InstanceID has multiple key and multiple values.
[image]

how do I rewrite the command to split each key string and value string so the output displays only one item, for example:

[image]

Comment: This is the THIRD time you have asked a question similar to this. Please stop this behavior. Remove your old question if you no longer need them. Next time just edit your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pipe what you have into a `ForEach` loop, and then inside that do a `For` loop for each key/value pair like:

```psh
Get-EC2Instance |Select -ExpandProperty RunningInstance | 
    select-object InstanceId,@{Name='Key'; Expression={$.Tag.Key} },@{Name='Value'; Expression={$_.Tag.Value} } |
    ForEach{
        $CurInst = $_
        For($i=0;$i -lt $CurInst.Key.Count;$i++){
            New-Object PSObject -Prop@{
                'InstanceId' = $CurInst.InstanceId
                'Key' = $CurInst.Key[$i]
                'Value' = $CurInst.Value[$i]
            } #End object properties
        } #End For Loop
    } #End ForEach Loop
```

That should output like what you want.